# how to give horizontal and vertical scrollar in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scroll

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  </head>
 <body>
   <div id="divScroll" style="width: 100%;overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: scroll;">

<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Name</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Name</td>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
     <td>abc</td>
  </tr>  
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Above is my HTMl code wm getting problem to
 to give horizontal and vertical scrollar in IE**

[See JSbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/isekok/1/edit#/isekok/4/edit)

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify height and width for the scroll to work

Change your

```
<div id="divScroll" style="width: 100%;overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: scroll;">
```

to

```
<div id="divScroll" style="width: 300px;height:200px;overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: scroll;">
```

You can also try this way

```
<div id="divScroll" style="width: 300px;height:200px;overflow:auto;">
```

check this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/isekok/6/edit)**

For your [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Apply some height like:  `height: 150px;` for vertical scrollbar...same as width for horizontal scroll..

```
<div id="divScroll" style="width: 100%;overflow: scroll; height: 150px;">
```

No need to apply twice overflow-x and overflow-y just use overflow..